# Where can I find an Amulet of Mara?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to find the Amulet of Mara so I can get married, but I can't find it and it doesn't seem to be at any of the stores. Is there any specific place I can find it?

Comment: Have you found it by now? If you've used the tips in the answer please mark it as accepted. FTR, I got the amulet after completing a quest in Markarth, can't remember its name but it involved rescuing a girl from Forsworn captivity.

Comment: Yes, sorry it took so long for me to get back to this question.

Comment: Is it actually possible to commit bigamy on skyrim? haha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can buy one from Maramal in Riften. He is usually in the Temple of Mara, and sells it for 200 gold. He also happens to be the guy who carries out the marriage ceremony, and explains the whole process before he'll sell one to you.

Comment: You can often find him in the tavern, too.

Comment: It can also be random loot from enemies. I found mine on a Bandit Thug. Maramal is a guarantee though.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

You can get the amulet from **Quest, Chests, Merchants, Random Loot and some Places**.

---

**Long answer/explanation**

**1. Quest**

The Amulet of Mara can acquired from the quest The **Book of Love**:

> - **Quest Giver:** Dinya Balu
> - **Location:** Temple of Mara in Riften
> - **Prerequisite:** Speak with Dinya Balu
> - **Reward:** Agent of Mara blessing, Amulet of Mara

**2. Chests**

> - Chests (general)
> - Chests in:
>
>   - **Mzinchaleft Depths** (hidden room underwater)
>   - **Blackreach** (war quarters)
>   - **Knifepoint Mine** (in the shack with Boethia's Champion during the quest Boethia's Calling)
>   - **Reachwind Eyrie**
>   - **Nchuand-Zel** (Control Room)
>   - **Fort Neugrad** (outside)

**3. Merchants**

> - **Temple of Mara in Riften:** speak with Maramal about the temple's beliefs after you meet him in The Bee and Barb, and he will present
>     you with the option to purchase one from him for 200 Gold
> - **Fort Dawnguard in Dayspring Canyon:** Sorine Jurard may have one for sale

**4. Random Loot**

> - **Dwemer cabinets**
> - **Random spawn** as dungeon loot
> - **Dead Bandit** (in a hay cart near a fire) in Northwatch Keep
> - In one of the two dead **Riften Guards** in Shor's Watchtower before "meet the men" in the quest Compelling Tribute, as an Imperial
> - Also may be found as loot for a dead or alive **Whiterun soldier** when fighting the first dragon in the main quest at the Western Watchtower
> - Rarely, some **Guards** are wearing it, and it is able to be pickpocketed

**5. Places**

> - **Bee and Barb** (an inn in the town of Riften and in Riften's Temple Of Mara)
> - **Stormcloaks General** (during the defense of Whiterun)
> - In a **tent along the coast northeast of Dawnstar** (From the entrance of the Dawnstar Sanctuary (facing the door), go left and follow the
>     beachline (you may encounter a few Horkers) until you see a battered
>     tent, the amulet will be inside on the left bedroll. If taking the
>     amulet, then returning after a few days, it might have respawned a new
>     one)
> - On the Emperor's ship, **the Katariah**
> - **Proudspire Manor** in Solitude (after purchasing the upgrades)
> - On the **boat at Orphan's Tear** (in a chest behind the table)
> - Next to the **word wall on Eldersblood Peak**
> - Inside the **wooded structure inside Labyrinthian**
> - In one of the upstairs bedrooms during the "Diplomatic Immunity" quest when you're in the **Thalmor Embassy**
> - In the **Ansilvund Burial Chambers**
> - In **Radiant Raiment** within Solitude
> - In **Madesi's storage** container with Madesi's ring during the mission A Chance Arrangement in Riften
>
> **NOTE:** Looting and wearing the enchanted versions of the Amulet of Mara found on NPCs will not function like a regular Amulet of Mara
>   until the player speaks to Maramal about marriage.

Source: [Amulet of Mara - The Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Amulet_of_Mara)

Comment: Just bought Proudspire Manor with all upgrades and there's no Amulet of Mara.

Comment: You can also buy it from the priest of the Mara Temple.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy an Amulet of Mara in Riften in the Bee & Barb, and there will be a priest — talk to him. He sells it for 200 gold.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the the Temple of Mara and talk to Dinya Balu, she will send you on a few easy quests. Afterwards, she'll give you an Amulet of Mara and you'll become an Agent of Mara which will give you a permanent +15% Resist Magicka.